# Template's data-type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class called `Variable`, with a specialized constructor for char*, which is defined as follows:

```
template<>
Variable<char*>::Variable(char * const &arg_value)
{
    value = new char[strlen(arg_value) + 1];
    strncpy(value, arg_value, strlen(arg_value));
    value[strlen(arg_value)] = '\0';
}
```

Now, I have this statement, that declares a `Variable<char*>`:

`Variable<char*> stringVar = const_cast<char*>("Hi");`

In my `Variable` definition, I never declared or defined a copy constructor to a const char*. However, the statement works perfectly fine. Why is this? I am quite positive that `stringVar` has a data-type of `Variable<char*>`, but this still works. Where is this assignment coming from?

Comment: An equals sign in the declaration is not an assignment.

Comment: `Variable` is not a template class. It's a *class template*.

Comment: Since you have a specialized constructor anyway, why not take the param as `const char*` instead of `char*const&`?  Also, calling `strlen` 3 times seems silly.  Cache the result.

Comment: The `const_cast` in `const_cast<char*>("Hi")` is ridiculously redundant.

Comment: @PaulManta, if I do not have the const_cast, it generates a warning: "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*". That apparently fixes it, but I'm not really sure how..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor that takes one argument allows for *implicit conversions*. Here's a simpler example of your situation:

```
struct Foo { Foo(int, double = 0.5, char = 'a') { } };

void bar(Foo);

Foo x = 1; // OK!
bar(2);    // also OK
```

To inhibit this implicit conversion, say `explicit`:

```
struct Eew { explicit Eew(int) { } };

// Eew e = 3;    // error
Eew e2 = Eew(3); // OK but weird
Eew e3(3);       // correct
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Variable<char*> stringVar = const_cast<char*>("Hi");
```

call implicit c-tor of class `Variable<char*>`.
It's equal to

```
Variable<char*> stringVar = Variable<char*>(const_cast<char*>("Hi"));
```

Comment: Oh, so when assigning data-type1 to data-type2, C++ will look in data-type1's constructors to see if any of them accept char* const as a parameter? Is this for all data types?

Comment: @ZERO it's not assigning. It's initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the default copy constructor. Declare one hidden in your Variable<> template and watch the compile break.

Comment: Isn't the copy constructor only for copying the same class?

Answer (score 1):

```
char hi[] = "Hi";
Variable<char*> stringVar = hi;
```

The second line above is *semantically* equivalent to:

```
Variable<char*> stringVar( implicit_cast<Variable<char*>>(hi) );
```

Assuming that there was such a thing as `implicit_cast` that performed a type conversion to the destination type if and only if there is an implicit conversion available. In your case, the constructor:

```
Variable<T>::Variable( T const & )
```

provides for the implicit conversion: `Variable<char*>::Variable( char * const & )` can be used to convert from `char*` to `Variable<char*>`.

Note that while semantically this is what happens, in reality the copy will be elided and the code will be compiled to the equivalent:

```
Variable<char*> stringVar(hi);
```

That is, after all checks have been performed: an implicit conversion from `hi` to the type is available, and the copy constructor can be called implicitly.